# ASP.Net Core 404 processing on IIS

Tags: c#, redirect, iis, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with 404 processing on IIS.

First, in `Startup.cs`:

```
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/{0}");

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                context.Items.Add("previousUrl", context.Request.Path);
            }
        });
```

Then:

```
    [Route("/404")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CustomNotFound([FromServices] Logger logger)
    {
        logger.Log($"{HttpContext.Items["previousUrl"]?.ToString()} has been accessed but not found");

        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        return View("~/Views/Shared/NotFound.cshtml");
    }
```

Locally it works fine - `previousUrl` is logged, custom error page is returned (url in browser stays like previousUrl - it is necessary for me). But when I deploy my app behind IIS, net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in Chrome is returned without any status code at all. I tried to change `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` to `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirect` and it worked but redirected the browser to "/404" which is not what I want.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever solve it?